# Python: How can I create a df with double index in rows and columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am a beginner, self-taught.

I want to create a DataFrame with double index in rows and columns.

What I have done is:

```
#! /usr/bin/python3.8

import sys  
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 
from numpy import loadtxt           
from numpy import savetxt
import math                         

filename = open(sys.argv[1], "r")
Matriz = loadtxt(sys.argv[1], comments="#", delimiter=",", unpack=False)
filename.close()

filename = open(sys.argv[2], "r") #opens the file in read mode
Atomos = filename.read().splitlines() #puts the file into an array
filename.close()

a=len(Matriz)
c=len(Atomos)
b=a*a
b=float(b)
d = np.arange(b).reshape(a,a)
adj = np.arange(a*a).reshape(a,a)
dist = np.arange(a*a).reshape(a,a)
suma = np.arange(a).reshape(a,1)
indice = np.arange(c).reshape(a,1)

for i in range(0,a):
    for j in range(0,a):
        d[i][j]=np.sqrt( ( Matriz[j][0] - Matriz[i][0] )**2 + ( Matriz[j][1] - Matriz[i][1] )**2 +( Matriz[j][2] - Matriz[i][2] )**2 )

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d, index=Atomos, columns=Atomos)
print(df1)
print(indice)
df_array=df1.to_numpy()
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=df_array, index=indice, columns=indice)
print(df2)
```

What I tried was: 1. create an initial df:

```
,C,O,O,C,H,H,H,C,C,H,H,H
C,0.0,1.205475107329386,1.3429319010227962,2.3430136323519886,3.22738313640333,2.640130058756468,2.6401484355574363,1.4784953771865779,2.4427526711622995,3.4404701049315856,2.6506415109695562,2.173942147030341
O,1.205475107329386,0.0,2.245467917547002,2.6443156030953032,3.702905546101439,2.6354536594179083,2.6355724561170515,2.3918864536893496,2.871975783234887,3.9479515489105172,2.5936449600745437,3.2896946757332293
O,1.3429319010227962,2.245467917547002,0.0,1.418915551312475,2.015476882415432,2.0693088134923188,2.0692958839669946,2.3236193736523485,3.560975969980456,4.431347320573397,3.951843753512012,2.4366421143893597
C,2.3430136323519886,2.6443156030953032,1.418915551312475,0.0,1.0868846056358739,1.0921261760040055,1.092126228351473,3.6419246237091034,4.772348473634059,5.725281935435472,4.948741644534887,3.855293676517857
H,3.22738313640333,3.702905546101439,2.015476882415432,1.0868846056358739,0.0,1.7916118321336392,1.7916073980710447,4.336840746006843,5.570012200282658,6.44436962662531,5.876935928592363,4.304036910039309
H,2.640130058756468,2.6354536594179083,2.0693088134923188,1.0921261760040055,1.7916118321336392,0.0,1.774322615322816,3.999843247699306,5.001451201004137,5.992370839831868,5.038926795069471,4.349546588337786
H,2.6401484355574363,2.6355724561170515,2.0692958839669946,1.092126228351473,1.7916073980710447,1.774322615322816,0.0,3.9999029642804302,5.001556219427222,5.992449776200327,5.039085741282741,4.349558376763068
C,1.4784953771865779,2.3918864536893496,2.3236193736523485,3.6419246237091034,4.336840746006843,3.999843247699306,3.9999029642804302,0.0,1.324770443414403,2.107792016824585,2.085364895492881,1.079295724832157
C,2.4427526711622995,2.871975783234887,3.560975969980456,4.772348473634059,5.570012200282658,5.001451201004137,5.001556219427222,1.324770443414403,0.0,1.0763707503087891,1.0781013610472885,2.1192372863195152
H,3.4404701049315856,3.9479515489105172,4.431347320573397,5.725281935435472,6.44436962662531,5.992370839831868,5.992449776200327,2.107792016824585,1.0763707503087891,0.0,1.8418880170159488,2.4949700018092598
H,2.6506415109695562,2.5936449600745437,3.951843753512012,4.948741644534887,5.876935928592363,5.038926795069471,5.039085741282741,2.085364895492881,1.0781013610472885,1.8418880170159488,0.0,3.067298402780731
H,2.173942147030341,3.2896946757332293,2.4366421143893597,3.855293676517857,4.304036910039309,4.349546588337786,4.349558376763068,1.079295724832157,2.1192372863195152,2.4949700018092598,3.067298402780731,0.0
```

Then, I tried to save it as an array. Then, again, create a second df by tried to indexing with a list of numbers. But... it did not work.

**How can I create a df with double index in rows and columns?**

**What i would like to obtain is:**

```
,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12
,C,O,O,C,H,H,H,C,C,H,H,H
1,C,0.0,1.205475107329386,1.3429319010227962,2.3430136323519886,3.22738313640333,2.640130058756468,2.6401484355574363,1.4784953771865779,2.4427526711622995,3.4404701049315856,2.6506415109695562,2.173942147030341
2,O,1.205475107329386,0.0,2.245467917547002,2.6443156030953032,3.702905546101439,2.6354536594179083,2.6355724561170515,2.3918864536893496,2.871975783234887,3.9479515489105172,2.5936449600745437,3.2896946757332293
3,O,1.3429319010227962,2.245467917547002,0.0,1.418915551312475,2.015476882415432,2.0693088134923188,2.0692958839669946,2.3236193736523485,3.560975969980456,4.431347320573397,3.951843753512012,2.4366421143893597
4,C,2.3430136323519886,2.6443156030953032,1.418915551312475,0.0,1.0868846056358739,1.0921261760040055,1.092126228351473,3.6419246237091034,4.772348473634059,5.725281935435472,4.948741644534887,3.855293676517857
5,H,3.22738313640333,3.702905546101439,2.015476882415432,1.0868846056358739,0.0,1.7916118321336392,1.7916073980710447,4.336840746006843,5.570012200282658,6.44436962662531,5.876935928592363,4.304036910039309
6,H,2.640130058756468,2.6354536594179083,2.0693088134923188,1.0921261760040055,1.7916118321336392,0.0,1.774322615322816,3.999843247699306,5.001451201004137,5.992370839831868,5.038926795069471,4.349546588337786
7,H,2.6401484355574363,2.6355724561170515,2.0692958839669946,1.092126228351473,1.7916073980710447,1.774322615322816,0.0,3.9999029642804302,5.001556219427222,5.992449776200327,5.039085741282741,4.349558376763068
8,C,1.4784953771865779,2.3918864536893496,2.3236193736523485,3.6419246237091034,4.336840746006843,3.999843247699306,3.9999029642804302,0.0,1.324770443414403,2.107792016824585,2.085364895492881,1.079295724832157
9,C,2.4427526711622995,2.871975783234887,3.560975969980456,4.772348473634059,5.570012200282658,5.001451201004137,5.001556219427222,1.324770443414403,0.0,1.0763707503087891,1.0781013610472885,2.1192372863195152
10,H,3.4404701049315856,3.9479515489105172,4.431347320573397,5.725281935435472,6.44436962662531,5.992370839831868,5.992449776200327,2.107792016824585,1.0763707503087891,0.0,1.8418880170159488,2.4949700018092598
11,H,2.6506415109695562,2.5936449600745437,3.951843753512012,4.948741644534887,5.876935928592363,5.038926795069471,5.039085741282741,2.085364895492881,1.0781013610472885,1.8418880170159488,0.0,3.067298402780731
12,H,2.173942147030341,3.2896946757332293,2.4366421143893597,3.855293676517857,4.304036910039309,4.349546588337786,4.349558376763068,1.079295724832157,2.1192372863195152,2.4949700018092598,3.067298402780731,0.0
```

The content of both files is:

**filename1**

```
0.000000000000000000e+00,1.205475107329385898e+00,1.342931901022796248e+00,2.343013632351988562e+00,3.227383136403330077e+00,2.640130058756467779e+00,2.640148435557436279e+00,1.478495377186577864e+00,2.442752671162299549e+00,3.440470104931585560e+00,2.650641510969556247e+00,2.173942147030341054e+00
1.205475107329385898e+00,0.000000000000000000e+00,2.245467917547002035e+00,2.644315603095303224e+00,3.702905546101439072e+00,2.635453659417908323e+00,2.635572456117051487e+00,2.391886453689349601e+00,2.871975783234887114e+00,3.947951548910517250e+00,2.593644960074543704e+00,3.289694675733229268e+00
1.342931901022796248e+00,2.245467917547002035e+00,0.000000000000000000e+00,1.418915551312474932e+00,2.015476882415431881e+00,2.069308813492318766e+00,2.069295883966994598e+00,2.323619373652348497e+00,3.560975969980455957e+00,4.431347320573396864e+00,3.951843753512012114e+00,2.436642114389359737e+00
2.343013632351988562e+00,2.644315603095303224e+00,1.418915551312474932e+00,0.000000000000000000e+00,1.086884605635873857e+00,1.092126176004005522e+00,1.092126228351472994e+00,3.641924623709103415e+00,4.772348473634059118e+00,5.725281935435472036e+00,4.948741644534886852e+00,3.855293676517856927e+00
3.227383136403330077e+00,3.702905546101439072e+00,2.015476882415431881e+00,1.086884605635873857e+00,0.000000000000000000e+00,1.791611832133639171e+00,1.791607398071044743e+00,4.336840746006843439e+00,5.570012200282658199e+00,6.444369626625309877e+00,5.876935928592362579e+00,4.304036910039308772e+00
2.640130058756467779e+00,2.635453659417908323e+00,2.069308813492318766e+00,1.092126176004005522e+00,1.791611832133639171e+00,0.000000000000000000e+00,1.774322615322815988e+00,3.999843247699306215e+00,5.001451201004137204e+00,5.992370839831868246e+00,5.038926795069470721e+00,4.349546588337785735e+00
2.640148435557436279e+00,2.635572456117051487e+00,2.069295883966994598e+00,1.092126228351472994e+00,1.791607398071044743e+00,1.774322615322815988e+00,0.000000000000000000e+00,3.999902964280430240e+00,5.001556219427222061e+00,5.992449776200326816e+00,5.039085741282741004e+00,4.349558376763067891e+00
1.478495377186577864e+00,2.391886453689349601e+00,2.323619373652348497e+00,3.641924623709103415e+00,4.336840746006843439e+00,3.999843247699306215e+00,3.999902964280430240e+00,0.000000000000000000e+00,1.324770443414402976e+00,2.107792016824585168e+00,2.085364895492880954e+00,1.079295724832157077e+00
2.442752671162299549e+00,2.871975783234887114e+00,3.560975969980455957e+00,4.772348473634059118e+00,5.570012200282658199e+00,5.001451201004137204e+00,5.001556219427222061e+00,1.324770443414402976e+00,0.000000000000000000e+00,1.076370750308789148e+00,1.078101361047288487e+00,2.119237286319515245e+00
3.440470104931585560e+00,3.947951548910517250e+00,4.431347320573396864e+00,5.725281935435472036e+00,6.444369626625309877e+00,5.992370839831868246e+00,5.992449776200326816e+00,2.107792016824585168e+00,1.076370750308789148e+00,0.000000000000000000e+00,1.841888017015948842e+00,2.494970001809259763e+00
2.650641510969556247e+00,2.593644960074543704e+00,3.951843753512012114e+00,4.948741644534886852e+00,5.876935928592362579e+00,5.038926795069470721e+00,5.039085741282741004e+00,2.085364895492880954e+00,1.078101361047288487e+00,1.841888017015948842e+00,0.000000000000000000e+00,3.067298402780731070e+00
2.173942147030341054e+00,3.289694675733229268e+00,2.436642114389359737e+00,3.855293676517856927e+00,4.304036910039308772e+00,4.349546588337785735e+00,4.349558376763067891e+00,1.079295724832157077e+00,2.119237286319515245e+00,2.494970001809259763e+00,3.067298402780731070e+00,0.000000000000000000e+00
```

**filename2**

```
C
O
O
C
H
H
H
C
C
H
H
H
```

Comment: What do you mean by "double index"? It's not clear what you're asking for. It would help if you [edit] your question to show the expected output. Did you mean a [heirarchical/multi index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html)?

Comment: @G.Anderson I have edited the question in order to show what I would like to obtain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(
    'filename1.txt', sep=',', header=None
)

with open('filename2.txt', mode='r') as f:
    cols = f.read().splitlines()

df.index = df.columns = pd.Index(enumerate(cols, start=1))
print(df)
```

which prints

```
            1         2         3   ...        10        11        12
             C         O         O  ...         H         H         H
1  C  0.000000  1.205475  1.342932  ...  3.440470  2.650642  2.173942
2  O  1.205475  0.000000  2.245468  ...  3.947952  2.593645  3.289695
3  O  1.342932  2.245468  0.000000  ...  4.431347  3.951844  2.436642
4  C  2.343014  2.644316  1.418916  ...  5.725282  4.948742  3.855294
5  H  3.227383  3.702906  2.015477  ...  6.444370  5.876936  4.304037
6  H  2.640130  2.635454  2.069309  ...  5.992371  5.038927  4.349547
7  H  2.640148  2.635572  2.069296  ...  5.992450  5.039086  4.349558
8  C  1.478495  2.391886  2.323619  ...  2.107792  2.085365  1.079296
9  C  2.442753  2.871976  3.560976  ...  1.076371  1.078101  2.119237
10 H  3.440470  3.947952  4.431347  ...  0.000000  1.841888  2.494970
11 H  2.650642  2.593645  3.951844  ...  1.841888  0.000000  3.067298
12 H  2.173942  3.289695  2.436642  ...  2.494970  3.067298  0.000000

[12 rows x 12 columns]
```

Comment: Thank you by I need the index in rows and columns

Comment: I have edited my question, I show what I would like to obtain.

Comment: Note @Another.Chemist that, as such, `pd.Index(enumerate(cols, start=1))` does the same thing as `pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(enumerate(cols, start=1))`. I suggest you to use the `MultIndex`'s method, since it makes things explicit and less confusing/ambigous/misleading regarding the downstream uses.

Comment: You will have one value too many in `cols` if the last line of `filename2.txt` ends with a "\n". You can slightly change the code to `cols = f.read().strip().split('\n')`

Comment: @mozway You are right. Do you know [str.splitlines](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines), it builtin-deals with extra lines specifically.

Comment: @keepAlive: I had forgotten about it, thanks!